# Intent for playing several videos

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to play several videos in player that user will select, like playlist. But I only know how to play one video. Here is my code

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(video_url, "video/*");

                context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: There is no standard `Intent` action for "play several videos", sorry. Also, when you are supplying content to other apps, please use concrete MIME types, not wildcards like `video/*`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Give me an example please.

Comment: `intent.setDataAndType(video_url, "video/mp4");` would be an example of using a concrete MIME type, if the `video_url` points to an MP4 video.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, this example is for playing one video. I want to play a playlist with videos. Is it possible?

Comment: As I wrote, there is no standard `Intent` action to play several videos, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe there is non-standart `Intent` action to play several videos?